# How to set Inbound Rule Name via Cloudformation in AWS

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to set the name of this Ingress Rule in my Security Group:

[image]

I've tried two methods and looked at the documentation and can't find a way to do it. I've tried:

```
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: icmp
        FromPort: 0
        ToPort: -1
        Name: Allow ICMP
        Description: Allow ICMP 
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

And I've tried this:

```
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: icmp
        FromPort: 0
        ToPort: -1
        Description: Allow ICMP 
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Allow ICMP
```

I've looked for examples, and I've looked through the documentation and I don't see a reference to this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Name` that you see in the console is the Name tag of the resource. Currently in CloudFormation both `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress` and `Ingress` objects in `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup` don't support tags (Tags for individual rules is a recent feature, added in [July 2021](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/07/amazon-ec2-adds-resource-identifiers-tags-vpc-security-groups-rules/). CloudFormation doesn't support all new features on release). If this is a crucial requirement you can use [Lambda backed custom CloudFormation resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) to create an AWS Lambda function which will tag the resource for you.